# ink.sapo.pt how to use this form validation (onSuccess callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, ink.sapo.pt

I've been trying for like 2 hours to get this form validator to work, but I can't..
http://ink.sapo.pt/javascript/Ink.UI.FormValidator.2/#Ink_UI_FormValidator_2-FormValidator_FormElement-FormElement
I mean, form gets validated when I press the submit button, and form posts data only after all fields are correctly.
But what I need is to actually set up the onSuccess callback, so that instead of using method="post", i can a function easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `neverSubmit` option to do this.

This is a rather obscure option, but it's there in the `FormValidator` class (you may be looking at the `FormElement` class, which refers to each input element in a form and takes options such as that input element's label and validation rules.)

I've made a short example based on the official sample.

http://jsbin.com/toruyo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Now I know how to use those options and other listed things thanks to you.